# Jquery Changing value of h1 tag on <select>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Similar to this Fiddle I found, http://jsfiddle.net/JBjXN/

I'm attempting to have it so when I select an option from

**HTML**

```
<h1>Select a Show</h1>
<select class="radio-line" id="radio-manager" name=“show”>
   <option value=“Show1“>Show 1 - May 9th 2017</option> 
   <option value=“Show2“>Show 2 - May 10th 2017</option>
   <option value=“Show3”>Show 3 - May 11th 2017</option>
</select>
```

It will then change the value of my  tag from *"Select a Show"* to other text! If someone could point me in the right direction or show me how I would go about doing this...

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can just twerk a bit on the demo and your good to go

Comment: Stackoverflow requires you to post your question with the code you have tried. Both the pieces of the puzzle jQuery detect change in dropdown and use jQuery to change h1 is on stack overflow. Its a matter of searching.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do something like:

```js
$(function() {

  //Add event listener to dropdown with class radio-line
  $('.radio-line').change(function() {

    //Get the text of the selected option. Not its value
    var text = $(this).find("option:selected").text();

    //Update the text of h1
    $('h1').text(text);

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Select a Show</h1>
<select class="radio-line" id="radio-manager" name=“show”>
 <option value=“Show1“>Show 1 - May 9th 2017</option> 
 <option value=“Show2“>Show 2 - May 10th 2017</option>
 <option value=“Show3”>Show 3 - May 11th 2017</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add an `.change(handler)`

```js
$(() => {
  $('#radio-manager').change((e) => {
    $('#to-change').text(`You selected: ${e.target.value}`)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <h1 id="to-change">Select a Show</h1>
  <select class="radio-line" id="radio-manager" name=“show”>
  <option value="Show1">Show 1 - May 9th 2017</option> 
  <option value="Show2">Show 2 - May 10th 2017</option>
  <option value="Show3">Show 3 - May 11th 2017</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.change` event listener:

```js
$('#radio-manager').on('change', function() {
  const val = $('#radio-manager').val();
  $('h1').text(val); 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <h1 id="to-change">Select a Show</h1>
  <select class="radio-line" id="radio-manager" name=“show”>
  <option value="Show1">Show 1 - May 9th 2017</option> 
  <option value="Show2">Show 2 - May 10th 2017</option>
  <option value="Show3">Show 3 - May 11th 2017</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`change`](https://api.jquery.com/change) event of jQuery.

```js
$('#radio-manager').change(function() {
  $('h1').text($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Select a Show</h1>
<select class="radio-line" id="radio-manager" name=“show”>
   <option value="Show1">Show 1 - May 9th 2017</option> 
   <option value="Show2">Show 2 - May 10th 2017</option>
   <option value="Show3">Show 3 - May 11th 2017</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

The .change event is what you are looking for. This event will allow you to run a function when the select items change:

```js
var h1 = $('.targetChange')

$('.target').change(function(e){
 h1.text($(this).val())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 class="targetChange">
Hello
</h1>

<form>
  <select class="target">
    <option value="option 1 selected" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option 2 selected">Option 2</option>
  </select>
</form>
<div id="other">
  Trigger the handler
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give id to h1 tag (whose value you want to change) like the below html

```
<h1 id='h1_head'>Select a Show</h1>
<select class='radio-line' id='radio-manager' name='show'>
<option value='Show1'>Show 1 - May 9th 2017</option> 
<option value='Show2'>Show 2 - May 10th 2017</option>
<option value='Show3'>Show 3 - May 11th 2017</option>
</select>
```

And then put below jquery inside script tag.

```
$("#radio-manager").change(function(){
    var dropdown = this;
  var dropdownValue = $(dropdown).val();
  console.log(dropdownValue);
  $("#h1_head").text(dropdownValue); 
});
```

Above JQuery fired when the value of 'Select' is changed. (If it not fired put it inside document ready i.e

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#radio-manager").change(function(){
        var dropdown = this;
        var dropdownValue = $(dropdown).val();
        $("#h1_head").text(dropdownValue); 
    });
});
```